# Identifying William Elijah Vedder's mother in New York City?

Tags: united-states, vital-records, new-york-city, 1860s

I have been searching online to find the mother of my great grandfather William Elijah Vedder.

His father, Elijah S Vedder, I have found in many records, but not in 1860. He had at least 4 different wives. A copy of my great grandfather's death certificate says that her name was Delia Gardner.

"The Vedder Family In America" book lists her name as Delia Gordon b. in Spiers, NY d. Oct 20, 1860 NYC during childbirth.

I cannot find any mention of her death or William's birth in the New York City Vital Record indices online.

What sources can I use to identify William's mother?

---

Upon searching the address where William got married, I found a sister and brother. The sister was born around 1865. My father always spoke of a brother George who was a carpenter, so this is very likely a match. This would seem to indicate that Delia did not die during childbirth, unless of course the sister was from a different mother

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the 2-minute [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A site because it operates differently to any bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.